# Test Craft Plugin without the use of a database

Tags: craft3

We'd like to add Unit Tests to our Craft Plugin. I have used the Plugin Factory generator to generate the files and the basic setup seems to work.

I am however struggling getting the tests to work without the need to use a database. This because our CI/CD is not set-up to work with a database at the moment. And the part we'd like to add test for doesn't require a database.

Within the codeception.yml file, I have set `dbSetup: {clean: false, setupCraft: false}`. But this still asks for valid database credentials. Then I was seeking into `fullMock: false`. But I can't seem to access `Cacheable::getInstance()`. It returns a `NULL`. Also adding the below to the Cacheable.php file in the src folder is never called.

```php
public function getComponentMap()
{
    return [
        [ContentService::class, ['getContentService', 'contentService']]
    ];
}
```

What am I missing here? Or is using a database a hard requirement?